# Jekyll blog hosted on GitHub Pages not rendering after a few minutes

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've made a blog website ([link to blog subdomain](https://blog.suneetmahajan.com/) / [link to repo with code](https://github.com/SMiles02/blog)) using the [Lanyon](https://lanyon.getpoole.com/) theme for Jekyll.

When I build the website locally via `jekyll serve`, it works fine. After I add, commit and push my changes, the blog renders fine.

After 10ish minutes however, the entire thing stops rendering and looks horrible.

Screenshot after pushing to GitHub:
[Screenshot after pushing to GitHub](https://i.imgur.com/1SZIYRY.png)

Screenshot after waiting a few minutes:
[Screenshot after waiting a few minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHa8z.png)

Note: when it initially is deployed from GitHub, it renders fine on http and not on https. After a while, it stops rendering on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [browser console](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html) mentions:

> Blocked loading [mixed active content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) “http://blog.suneetmahajan.com/public/css/poole.css”

I would:

- use HTTPS everywhere (like in [your `_config.yml`](https://github.com/SMiles02/blog/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml#L5) )
- avoid `absolute-url` in [`gh-pages/_includes/head.html`](https://github.com/SMiles02/blog/blob/gh-pages/_includes/head.html#L19-L21)

So you should not need `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/public/css/poole.css' | absolute_url }}">`.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/poole.css">` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed my issues and is very helpful to know!